# jquery div show and hide problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem. When I first time press on the link div show's then when I press on document it's disappear. When I press second time on link div appears and suddenly  disappears. What's wrong?

```
$(function() {
$("#trigger").click(function() {
    $('#toolWrapper').toggle(function() {
        $(document).click(function(event) {
            if (!($(event.target).is('#toolWrapper') || $(event.target).parents('#toolWrapper').length || $(event.target).is('#trigger'))) {
                $('#toolWrapper').hide(500);
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

});

Comment: That seems to be what you're telling it to do. What is the _expected_ behavior?

Comment: Why are you binding a `.click()` handler *inside* the other click handler? The second time `#trigger` is clicked you'll then bind a second `.click()` handler to the document. On the third click you'll bind a third. And so forth.

Comment: how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have nested your callbacks - so you are only setting your event callbacks inside other ones. I imagine this is what is causing your problems.

In your trigger event handler, if you use `event.stopPropagation();` then you can stop the document event handler being called, so you don't have to check if it is an event target.

Is this what you are trying to do? [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kaayoqon/)

[Edit]: Added code to answer:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#toolWrapper').hide();
});

$("#trigger").click(function(event) {
    $('#toolWrapper').show();
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function() {
    if (!$(event.target).is('#toolWrapper') || $(event.target).parents('#toolWrapper').length) {
        $("#toolWrapper").hide(500);
    }
});
```

Comment: Well I trying to make popup dialog box, but i don't know ho to fix this problem. Maybe can you fix this code?

Comment: I think this is what you were trying to do... [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/kaayoqon/)

Comment: @k212, You missed the argument "event" in last function. Otherwise it is working fine.